# How does conda's source activate foo work

Tags: macos, bash, python

Anaconda's documentation for [managing environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) states that activating an environment is done using:

```
source activate <env-name>
```

I've noticed that with conda installed, `activate` is in the path:

```
$ which activate
/Users/dilum/anaconda/bin/activate
```

Does source find files in the path as well? And I suppose the second parameter (the environment-name) is simply processed by the `activate` script?

Answer (score 17):

Found details for the builtin `source` in [ss64's man pages](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html).

> Unless you provide an exact path to filename then bash will look first via the PATH variable and then in the current directory (only if filename is not found in $PATH.) If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when filename is executed. Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.

So,

```
source activate <env-name>
```

is calling `/Users/dilum/anaconda/bin/activate` and passing the desired environment name as an argument.